# Custom methods in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, debugging

Just curious, is it possible to set custom methods in MongoDb.
I know there is a way to set [stored functions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/). But I need stored method, not a function.

Let's say we have the code that returns an array of users' names:

```
db.users.find({}, {name:1, _id:0}).toArray().map(function(doc) {return doc.name})
```

It would be nice if I could set custom method 'only', so the above code would transform into:

```
db.users.find({}, {name:1, _id:0}).only('name')
```

I need this just for more convenient debugging.

Thank you.

Comment: @Zoltan.Tamasi No he specifically states not that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed, you are wondering about adding your own mini function to the mongo console right?

You just put it into your `mongorc`: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-mongorc-file